Is there a way to automate adding the "Chapter" or "Figure" label when using \ref, similar to how \eqref automatically adds brackets?
I would like to define commands like \eqref for referencing chapters, figures, theorems and so on.
Instead of having to write "In Chapter \ref{ch1}, we discuss...", I could write something like "In \chref{ch1}, we discuss..." and have it print the word chapter before the chapter number. Ideally, I would like to have the hyperlink be for the whole string "Chapter 1" instead of just the number containing the link. I don't want to use the chapter name instead of the number, I just want the word "Chapter" to be automatic.
Is it possible to define a new command like this?

\autoref{ch1}. Or use a package like zref-clever.

Another possibility is the cleveref package and its user macros, such as \cref and \crefrange. cleveref must be loaded after hyperref.

Ideally, I would like to have the hyperlink be for the whole string "Chapter 1" instead of just the number containing the link.

Be sure to load cleveref with the option nameinlink.

Observe that \cref, unlike \autoref, can take more than one argument. \crefrange, in contrast, takes exactly 2 arguments. Use \Cref instead of \cref to generate a word label that starts with an uppercase letter; if you want all word labels to start with an uppercase letter, I suggest you load the package with the option capitalize ("capitalise" works too). The cleveref package features extensive language adaptations. For more information, see the package's user guide, which you may load in a pdf viewer by type texdoc cleveref at a command prompt.
\documentclass{book} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}
\begin{document}

\refstepcounter{chapter} \label{chap:A}
\refstepcounter{chapter} \label{chap:B}
\refstepcounter{chapter} \label{chap:C}
\refstepcounter{chapter} \label{chap:D}

A cross-reference to \cref{chap:A}.

Cross-references to \cref{chap:D,chap:B}.

Cross-references to \crefrange{chap:A}{chap:D}.

\end{document}


Thank you so much! This is exactly what I was looking for.

@AliceMarkham be aware that cleveref hasn't been updated since 6 years and currently has various issues with a current hyperref and LaTeX. Search the site for recent questions.

@UlrikeFischer - The uses of \cref and \crefrange I gave in my answer shouldn't give rise to the potential issues you mention. Knock on wood... :-)

@Mico  It affects all cleveref commands if one of the patch that update the cleveref data fail and the newest issue is with a simple \cref: https://github.com/latex3/hyperref/issues/362.

@UlrikeFischer - It looks like I may have been a tad over-optimistic regarding cleveref's stability.

@Mico it is a tad hard if the maintainer does not react. cleveref is around 8000 lines long, and it redefines commands (both public and internal ones) from lots of packages and the kernel.

@Mico It's working alright with my other packages compiled in Overleaf for now! Will likely use a different package in the future, but if it ain't broke (and the deadline is tomorrow) don't fix it :)

@alice - Good news, for sure! Congrats in advance on meeting your deadline.

In place of \ref, you can use the \autoref command from the hyperref package.

An example with the zref-clever package:
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{zref-clever}
\zcsetup{cap}

\begin{document}

\chapter{title}
\label{chap}

\begin{figure}
\caption{text}
\label{fig}
\end{figure}

See \zcref{fig} in \zcref{chap}

\end{document}


